# Moving Vim Plugins to a separated file

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, macvim

I want to separate my Vim Plugins to a separated file since I using more plugins in my `.vimrc` file. it this possible?

Comment: You might want to have a look at the plugins Pathogen and Vundle. Both allow you to easily manage plugins. Pathogen gives you a bit more control over what is going on while Vundle makes things a bit easier.

Answer (score 0):

`source` command can do it.

You can separate files, and source them in the main file ( vimrc )

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to correctly understand your question.

Usually when the `.vimrc` contains more and more functions, mappings, commands, abbreviations and so on, we split it into several files.

When the definitions should apply to any type of buffer (/file), they go in a vim script stored under `~/.vim/plugin/` (I simplify, read `:h 'rtp'` for more information).

When the definitions are specifics to a type of buffer (/file), they go in filetype plugins, stored under `~/.vim/ftplugin/{filetype}/`.

Functions are best stored in autoload plugins. Syntax definitions in ~/.vim/syntax/` and so on.

I'm quite sure I've already explained that somewhere. May be it was on SO, I don't remember.